# DateTime breaking code PHP

Tags: php

My code is:

```
$etime = $arr['od'];
$ds = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($etime));
$timezone=new DateTimeZone("UTC"); // declare whatever your timezone is
$etimed=new DateTime($ds,$timezone);  // resultset datetime
```

`$arr['od']` is `2017-08-20 19:05:59`, trying to echo `$etimed` it breaks my code but I don't know why?

Comment: Nothing in the error logs? The page is serving as a 500?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datetime is an object, it cannot be echoed like that, therefore you need to format the datetime to echo it like the code below:

```
$etime = $arr['od'];

$ds = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($etime));

$timezone=new DateTimeZone("UTC"); // declare whatever your timezone is
$etimed=new DateTime($ds,$timezone);  // resultset datetime

echo $etimed->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```